# Input 4 Letter and 4 Number No Special Character only limit but allow function Keys?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, web, mozilla

I want to limit my text input to have only 4 letters then 4 numbers and no special character and  no white space.

and code i wrote :

```
inputText.addEventListener("keydown", (e) => {
    if (e.key === "Enter") {
        if (!inputText.checkValidity()) {
            alert('Pattern not matched!!')
            return;
        }
    }
    let pos = e.target.selectionStart;
    pos < 4 ? /^[A-Z]$/.test(e.key) ? '' : e.preventDefault() : /^[0-9]$/.test(e.key) ? '' : e.preventDefault();

})
```

Now the problem is if i try to delete a input value from the field i can't as i prevented it with the current code i am only able to allow number and letters.

Now in order to allow them i have to do the `Keycode` based approach But `keyCode` is deprecated.

How to only allow `4 Letter > 4 Letter` No white space No special character. And allow function button to work like backspace shift tab and all..

Comment: You can try with this. It should work. https://www.techrepublic.com/article/restrict-keyboard-input-with-this-quick-and-easy-javascript/

Comment: @dd_ that link does not contains any information that could extend my information or could help me about this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not commenting too much on the general structure of what you are attempting to accomplish, the easiest way of just trapping the backspace key:

```js
if (e.key === "Enter") {
    if (!inputText.checkValidity()) {
        alert('Pattern not matched!!')
        return;
    }
} else if (e.key === 'Backspace') {
    return;
}
```

The `else if` part would need to be extended to the other keys you are attempting to escape from the processing (e.g. `else if (e.key === 'Backspace' || e.key === 'ArrowLeft')`).

The key values to consider can be found on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/key/Key_Values).

An alternative could be to turn the problem around and exclude all the characters you don't want and allow the rest through.

I would normally advocate for post processing of the text input rather than preventing the entering thereof - so when the user enters a text input, test the complete entry rather than preventing the bad entry.

Keyboard entry has a number of permutations so it can be a little murky in dealing with at this level. However, this may not fit with your requirement.

Comment: `if (e.key === 'Backspace' || e.key === 'ArrowLeft')` adding every key is kinda boilerplate which i didn't wanted to do. That was the reason of asking the question. in general about function  (except shift) key i don't think they do much in input but for safety i think it would be great.

Comment: And doing so will also disable combined keys such as copy and paste.

Comment: Yeah - that's the downside of trying to only accept certain characters and prevent others. I don't think you're going to get away from boilerplate code at this level. To allow the browser to do it for you, you would need to change your strategy and handle the problem at a different level (as suggested). At the key level you're rolling your own handler so any way you do that will result in a certain amount of boilerplate code.